# What are these "X"s / crosses on this schematic's wiring? Traces attached to the metal housing (ground)?

Tags: ground, schematics, symbol, cases, chassis

Below is a section of the schematic for the RF modulator of a Nintendo NES-001 system. I am curious what these Xs are that I've boxed in red below. Looking at my own NES-001 and matching locations, I think these points are where the board's ground connection is soldered to the grounded metal housing. I've been unable to find anything regarding this specific symbol.

[image: Section of Nintendo NES-001 RF Modulator Schematic]

Comment: I notice they're all at crossings. Is that significant, perhaps?

Comment: @Felthry I _believe_ that winding line that the wires touch at the Xs is essentially the outline of the housing for the modulator. Direct link to the entire schematic is here: https://console5.com/techwiki/images/5/58/NES-001-Schematic---Power%2C-AV%2C-RF-Switch.png

Answer (score 5):

Based on the [more complete schematic](http://www.freeinfosociety.com/electronics/schemview.php?id=2405) it seems fairly obvious that the continuous line around the outside represents the metal shielding can.

The X's seem to be where circuit traces or connectors escape the can, such as the connections to the regulator. The actual connections (other than the user connectors) seem to be a long header that pokes through a hole in the can. [Video showing modulator](https://www.game-tech.us/hi-def-nes-install-guides-nes-001-front-loader-2-capacitor-replacement/)

Comment: Yeah it seems that way, and the X part may be saying that they don't touch the shielding. Kind of like non-touching, intersecting traces drawn with a bump at the intersection.

Comment: @rossy__  Seems quite non-intuitive. Perhaps the designer was struggling with the limitations of the software (or, 25+  years ago, maybe their plastic drafting stencil).

Answer (score 1):

You've cropped the schematic too much and haven't included a hyperlink to the source.

Noting that the power jack breaks that line it appears to be either the case or the edge of the PCB. As the components inside the line are probably on the PCB. The crosses are some kind of connection points - possibly for flying leads.

> Traces attached to the metal housing (ground)?

No. If that were true many points of the system would be short-circuited, including the power supply.

Comment: Ah, maybe the Xs mean that those traces go through the housing without touching the housing. Kind of like the bumps drawn on non-touching intersecting traces perhaps?